# Make sliding slideshow? - need a Video Editor (Tried Movie Maker/Premiere Pro)

Tags: windows, video

I have a set of pictures and I want to make a video out of it so that pictures move left at a constant speed (*or a set velocity if possible*), one after another.

Basically, I need a sliding slideshow. Exported as a video if possible.

The pictures **should just slide like its one long picture moving left.**

I need a software to do it. Possibly a video editor, since I don't see how to do it in something like Windows Movie Maker.

I also would like *gamma color correction* feature for the entire video (but it is not mandatory).

---

I'm running windows; need preferably the simplest thing that could do the job done. Paid software only if there are no good alternatives.

Can I do this in *Adobe Premiere Pro*? **Edit**: I believe it offers the desired effect to slide pictures, but It lags too much and does not load the pictures in the same order as they were sorted in the folder. (For comparison, *Windows Movie Maker* does not lag and loads pictures in order, but does not have the desired effect to move pictures along.)

Comment: If you're comfortable programming, [AviSynth](http://avisynth.nl/) should be able to do it.

Comment: @jamesdlin Do you know of some tutorial that shows the basic functions that I can use to load and slide images? If not, I'll check it anyway,

Comment: It's been awhile since I've used AviSynth, but I think you could use a combination of [ImageSource](http://avisynth.nl/index.php/ImageSource), [StackHorizontal](http://avisynth.nl/index.php/StackHorizontal), [Animate](http://avisynth.nl/index.php/Animate), and [Crop](http://avisynth.nl/index.php/Crop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. Moviemaker actually could do this, but probably you did not make the right approach.

> one long picture moving left

If you need a long picture you could assemble a long picture, not a series of images.

Then you can use **Gimp** to assemble them and use Movie Maker with one of the panning movements it has.

But Probably you are looking for a compositing program.

A nice Free alternative is **Hit Film Express** and of course, you can use **Blender** too. Another free alternative is using Davinci Resolve's Dynamic Zoom tool.

That is if you really need a movie.

If you do not, because you need this on a webpage, you probably should use a **CSS animation**.

Answer (score 1):

Having just posted an answer to an unrelated video editor question, I believe the same answer may also suit your purposes.

[Kdenlive](https://kdenlive.org/) has a windows version, adding to the linux version already in place. It supports transitions in the same manner as many other non-linear video editors, although this is a free program.

[image]

I believe that you would have to set the transition time and the display time for each image to enable your objective to have a continuous flow. Alternatively, you may consider to [combine the pan and zoom effect (video tutorial)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TRbfXX_fpds) with the timing of the transitions and display period of each image.

I did not research the possibility of automating the process using scripts or macros, which may also be useful if you have a large quantity of images to process and can determine a set of parameters.